# What are good sources for Open-Source fonts?

Tags: resource-recommendations, free, font-recommendation, open-source

What are good sources for Open-Source fonts?

Note that by "Open-Source" I don't mean only free, but truly "open, free to modify and published under an Open Source license" fonts. These are still very rare.

I know of two:

- [The Open Font Library](http://openfontlibrary.org/)
- [The League of Movable Type](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/)

Any others?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Google font directory
https://www.google.com/fonts

The fonts are free (as in beer and as in speech). Most of them are using the [SIL Open Font License](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL_web), but not all of them.

Comment: I don't know if the fonts themselves are open source or just free. I don't think the outlines have been released.

Comment: @DKuntz: From what I can see, they are all licensed under either the SIL license, which is fully free or the Apache license.  I'm not really up on where the free beer/speech line is drawn by font designers.

Comment: To clarify (as one of the designers of the project): the part critical to copyright law are not the shapes of the letters, but the software representation of outlines, kerning, OT features etc. And that's all libre -- you can get the source files for all fonts on the GFD from their Google Code/Mercurial repository.

Answer (score 14):

Fonts included with Linux distros are usually Open Source. This would include these major families:

- [Liberation](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/)
- [Bitstream Vera](http://www.gnome.org/fonts/)
- [Nimbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Sans#Nimbus_Sans_L)
- [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page)

The Wikipedia page [Free software Unicode typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_Unicode_typefaces) list many others.  Additionally, another well-known Open Source font is the [Ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/), now used as the default sans font in the 10.10 release of the operating system as well as all branding.

[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) also has a large catalogue of Open Source fonts, though it mostly curates free fonts and there's no way to filter by licensing.

Answer (score 9):

The Liberation fonts are GPL-licensed and designed to be compatible with the most common fonts shipped in Windows: https://www.redhat.com/promo/fonts/

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any additional aggregate sources beyond what has already been mentioned, but you might want to check out GUST's TeX Gyre fonts:  http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/

Answer (score 4):

Adobe just released [Source Sans](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcesans.adobe/files/). It has a lot of promise. And you'll note that it's hosted on Sourceforge, where by searching for [font](http://sourceforge.net/directory/freshness%3arecently-updated/?q=fonts) or [typeface](http://sourceforge.net/directory/freshness%3arecently-updated/?q=typeface) I found a handful of other projects.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), there is also [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/).

If you are a developer or designing a web application, take a look at [NPM typeface packages](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces). This allow you to download and self-host fonts instead of using a CDN like Google Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

- There's the SIL fonts themselves: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=FontDownloads
- Recently, I've found the EB Garamond, which is close to completion: http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/index.html
- The sortmill project has fonts under the MIT license: http://code.google.com/p/sortsmill/
- I really like the Linux Libertine and Biolinum fonts: http://www.linuxlibertine.org/

The OpenFont Library wiki has a [nice list](http://openfontlibrary.org/wiki/Existing_Libre/Open_Fonts).

Answer (score -3):

I use [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/).

It's really free great resource for fonts

Comment: But not necessarily open source.