# In What Situations Am I Required to License Fonts From Its Original Creator?

Tags: font-licensing

In what situations am I required to license fonts from its original creator? For example, if I design a poster or a card for personal use and I use a font I have downloaded online or have paid for the use of it, do I have to license the font?

What if I am using the font for commercial purposes? (Websites, phone apps, ...)

Comment: Re "if I .... have paid for the use of it, do I have to license the font?" Not sure if I need to clarify this, but paying for use of a font *is* licencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses and rights vary by creator, and you need to read the license that comes with the fonts you are using for details.

In general, you need a license for each person who is using a font and a license for the printer, though the latter varies even more than the former. Redistribution of a font for electronic purposes is still relatively new and may require special permission if not a separate license from the creator if not explicitly given in the agreement that was sent with the font files.

You'll want to look at [this question for a more detailed discussion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/523/do-i-need-to-license-fonts-included-with-my-os/) of how it all works.