# Adobe Illustrator Font Licensing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, licensing

Do I need to buy a license to use fonts bundled with Adobe Illustrator for commercial use?

Comment: Related: [Do I need to license fonts included with my OS?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/523/52050)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Adobe's EULAs regarding their Fonts](http://www.adobe.com/products/type/font-licensing/end-user-licensing-agreements.html), fonts acquired either sepparatedly or bundled with one of their apps gives you permission to fully use it on **derivative works**. Or else  it would be quite pointless do bundle them to begin with.

What you are NOT allowed is to **distribute the font itself** to someone that does not owns a license.

You can actually see these legal issues in action when you try to export a PDF from Illustrator with a font which its license doesn't allow you to incorporate it in PDF files, Illustrator simply will not embed it and replace by something like Myriad Pro. Any other fonts bundled with Adobe's software, or one with PDF Embedding License will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://goo.gl/s0Rfj5), you can use the fonts for **printing** but not for **distribution**.